# How do I enable a module by exporting the configuration?

Tags: 8, importing-exporting, configuration

I enabled these core modules: Language, Content translation, Config translation, and Interface translation. I exported the core.extensions.yml file, but when I placed the same file in the development environment, those modules weren't installed.

How can I install modules by exporting the configuration?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's actually asking for [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/configuration-management) which can be found on drupal.org.

Comment: Did you actually import the configuration in the development environment? If yes, you'll need to provide more information, specially if you followed the standard steps to move configuration between environments. We need to know if you are not following the documentation, or if there's an actual problem in your site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import the configuration from the file, into the database. Configuration files are only a backup to configuration. The active configuration is in the database.

You can import configuration at `/admin/config/development/configuration` or run `drush cim`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the configuration files after you export them.
Either from the UI by going to *configuration > configuration sync*.
Or using `drush cim -y` or `drush csim -y` if you were using config split.